# Can you connect to WiFi - "N" if your card only supports "B/G"?

Tags: wireless-networking

In my network utility I see networks and they they say B/G/N on some on some its saying B/G on them.
So if I have card thats only B/G and access point is B/G/N I still can connect in G mode?

So then if I have card that supports N card how I know I am in connected in right mode it choses highest it can automatically?

Comment: We'll need a lot more detail to formulate an answer. But in general, the wireless manager utility for your OS should tell you which mode, etc. it's currently connected in.

Comment: generally NICs will be configured by default to choose the highest available, but you should also be able to specify in the NIC settings. What card and what OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

> Can you connect to WiFi - “N” if your card only supports “B/G”?

Not pure 802.11n, there's a "mixed mode" that makes it compatible for these devices.

> So if I have card thats only B/G and access point is B/G/N I still can connect in G mode?

It's rare for consumer B/G/N APs to only broadcast 802.11n, typically they broadcast all three unless you turn particular standards off. Otherwise they'd be called N APs, if B/G devices couldn't connect to them.

So yes, your B/G card will connect to the B/G/N AP. It should connect using 802.11g

> So then if I have card that supports N card how I know I am in connected in right mode it choses highest it can automatically?

Yes.